# Looping through a list of checkboxes array to insert multiple record in ruby on rails 3.1 in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, checkbox

I have a list of check boxes created with `check_box_tag` (`<%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", user.id %>`).
Now i want to loop through all the check-boxes based on users_ids in controller and insert data of all the users selected.

Comment: Enumeration? In Ruby typically `<class>.each`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Meltemi says, the usual way to iterate  in ruby is `.each`. In your case, probably something like this, in the controller that receives the form:

```
params[:user_ids].each do |user_id|
  u = User.find(user_id)
  u.do_something_to_that_user  #call a method or some such on the user
  something_else.users << u    #associate that user with something else
end
```

Alternatively, it can often be more efficient to do all of this in one go, though the exact form thereof depends on what you're doing with the user. For instance, if you want to associate the checked users with some record:

```
Record.user_ids = params[:user_ids]
```

Or if you want to update all of those users in some way:

```
User.where(:id => params[:user_id]).update_all(:attribute => some_value)
```

Comment: Also, be mindful that `update_all` _won't_ run validations or callbacks, in case you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys.It wasn't exactly what i wanted but still i was able to figure it out what i had to do with you guys help.